# Showing progress view in corresponding cell when click a download button in a tableview cell

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I am struck in my project at some task (i.e),I have a table view with 66 rows.In that i am placed different book names for each cell and place a download button to each book.My requirement is when we click on download button it shows the progress view in that particular cell only but i am getting in that particular cell but when i am drag the tableview it will shows the progress views in some that cells also.It is because of dequeue reusability concept but i dont know how to avoid this problem.I want even after drag the tableview it shows the progress view on the cell which i am click the download button (cell)

here is my code below..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    return 66;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UIButton *downloadButton = nil;
    CustomCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
  //here custom cell is another class in that we have the title label declaration
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(220,10,50,30);
        [downloadButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downloadButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        downloadButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        downloadButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        downloadButton.highlighted = YES;
        downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"tag is %d",indexPath.row);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:downloadButton];
}    


   NSString *titleLabel = [[appDelegate getBookNames]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.TitleLabel.text = titleLabel;


    return cell;
}

-(void)downloadButtonClicked:(id)sender{
  int index = [sender tag];
    NSLog(@"index of the cell is %d",index);
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[button superview] superview];

    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    NSLog(@"label text =%@",titleLabel.text);
    selectedBookTitle = titleLabel.text;
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableArray *allDownloadLinks;
    biblePlayerViewController = [[BiblePlayerViewController alloc]init]; 
   allDownloadLinks = [biblePlayerViewController allDownloadLinks];
    NSLog(@"all Download Links are %@",allDownloadLinks);
    biblePlayerViewController.indexOfSelectedBookTitle = [[appDelegate getBookNames]indexOfObject:selectedBookTitle];


    Download* download = [Download downloadWithTitle:selectedBookTitle url:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.audiotreasure.com/%@.zip",[allDownloadLinks objectAtIndex:(biblePlayerViewController.indexOfSelectedBookTitle)]]]PathtoSave:documentsPath];
    [[DownloadManager sharedDownloadManager] queueDownload: download];

   UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    progressView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 300, 20);
    [tableViewCell.contentView addSubview:progressView];

}
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Rdi.png) of my project is [output of my above code which is in simulator]

Answer (score 0):

you should nil the cell every time in cellForRow. This way it will not be re-used and allocated every time. It should work pretty fine in your case as your tableview is not very large. Just add the following line before cell == nil check:

```
cell = nil;
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, one way to avoid it is to just lock the scrolling ability of the table during the download.